# Is there any chance that SocketIO client could miss an event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

The SocketIO client subscribes to database update events. Can it happen that the event is not delivered and the client has not updated data? Or as long as the connection is established, the event will definitely be delivered?

Comment: socket.io can use a number of different transport mechanisms. Some of them are client polling, so the granularity will depend on the polling frequency.

Comment: Never ever trust client side data to be what you expect it to be! Technically, as long as the connection is stable, the client should have the updated data. But you never know if the client injected the client side code to change their data or somehow disregard the data received from the server. That's why you should _always_ assume that the data on the client side is unreliable and always verify it server side.